# Android: customize oval button with a image

Tags: android, xml, image, button, shapes

I want to create a customize button that have the shape of a round image I have created with CS6.

[image]

To customize a button first it is needed to define a drawable element.

If I want to use 2 diferent images depending on the state of the button, I can define an .xml (**customize_button.xml**) like follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn1"   />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn2" /> 

</selector>
```

Where btn1 and btn2 will be 2 .png images placed in the drawable folder.

If I want to make a button with an oval shape, the xml file I should write would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#6586F0"
        android:centerColor="#D6D6D6"
        android:endColor="#4B6CD6"
        android:angle="90"/>

</shape>
```

Finally, if I would like to add this customized button to my applications I just would need to add in the layout:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnPrueba"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/customize_button"  

/>
```

**My problem:**

By default a button will be squared, so if I want to add a image in the background that is oval, there will be a white gap around it. Do anyone knows how could I combine both .xml files in one?

Comment: why create a oval drawable when you have already a png image?

Comment: The png has got by default a squared white background shape. I don't know if it's possible to remove it with some program

Comment: You want your button to be oval shaped on enabled/normal state and btn1 on pressed??

Comment: @Minishika No, I want a round button like the image. The problem is, I don't know how to remove the white background. I was trying several things but I'm not able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the background of your image is white so what you need to do is

**Solution:**

You could use photoShop and

Use the lasso to cut of the background so it will be transparent